# jq-the resizable div width is not match with table data

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table and some div .the div are bedraggle when i resize the div its width shown in a text box this is my code

```js
$(function() {
    var container = $('#container'),
    base = null,
    handle = $('.handle'),
    isResizing = false,
    screenarea = screen.width;
    handle.on('mousedown', function(e) {
        base = $(this).closest(".timescalebase");
        isResizing = true;
        lastDownX = e.clientX;
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
        if (!isResizing)
            return;
        var k = $('#' + base[0].id + '_start').val(),
            p = (e.clientX - base.offset().left),
            q = parseInt((p / screenarea) * p);

        base.css('width', p);
        $('#' + base[0].id + '_value').val(q + parseInt(k));
    }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
        // stop resizing
       isResizing = false;
    });
});
```

```css
.editableTable {
    position:static;
    width:100%; 
    border-collapse:collapse;
} 
.editableTable td { 
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: lightgray;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:17px;
    /*max-height:10px;*/
 }
 .editableTable th {
     border: 1px solid;
     border-color: lightgray;
     height: 17px;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
 .activelevel1 {
     background-color: #EA623E;
 }
 .timescalebase {
     margin-top: 13px;
     height: 7px;
     position: relative;
     width:100px;
     height:7px;
  }
  .handle {
     position: absolute;
     right:0;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 8px;
     cursor: w-resize;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div style="margin-left:100px;">
        <div id="container" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;">
            <div id="timebase1" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
                <div class="handle"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="timebase2" class="timescalebase activelevel1">
                <div class="handle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
            <table class="editableTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>60</td>
                    <td>90</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div style="margin-top:100px;">
        start1 <input id="timebase1_start" type="text" name="number" value="0" min="1" class="usereditingsub1">
        stop 1<input id="timebase1_value" type="text" name="number" value="0" min="1" class="usereditingsub1">
        start2 <input id="timebase2_start" type="text" name="number" value="0" min="1" class="usereditingsub1">
        stop 2<input id="timebase2_value" type="text" name="number" value="0" min="1" class="usereditingsub1">
    </div>
```

my requirement is when i resize the div the  width that shown in  text box is must match with table value
means when I resize the width into on 30 or 60 or 90(the table value) the value of text box is same as that(means if the div width reach the table value 30 the text box value must shown 30

[Demo jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6667/)

Comment: Not clear with what you want.. Is it like you want the text box to show 30 only even if the width reaches 34 or something between 30 and 60??

Comment: the table indicate just like a scale from 0 to 90 .

Comment: Yea I understand that part. What I don't understand is your requirement. When i try to run your code, I can see the text box showing the exact width of it

Comment: yes nidhin , actually i need the end point of the div in text box(not it width)

Comment: @aswathy can you provide demo running code or jsfiddle .? so that we can check

Comment: @NidhinSG even i can't understand the requirement may b some confusion is there so adding jsfiddle here

Comment: @aswathy  Do you mean something like this  https://jsfiddle.net/zw9854og/

Comment: @Nidhin requirement is correct but i am  not intrested your  code.is there any change in my code to get like this.

Comment: try this.. https://jsfiddle.net/zw9854og/1/

Comment: oh you don't want to use resizable.. ok got it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zw9854og/2/   try this, you guys need to adjust the value accordingly

Comment: Tanks @nidhin its good but i don't understand this line   l = parseInt(p * (30/ 105));  please explain

Comment: Those values you need to find dynamically.. What i did is like provided a fixed width to td(the scales that shows 0-30-60-90 etc).. And the width of the div is 105 when it reaches the scale's 30 mark.. these values must be updated dynamically to make it perfect in all browsers